Why is paystack not verifying my CAC number?
I am having problems with my PayStack account not verifying my business CAC number even though it is correct and it has been verified directly from CAC site.
I have tried several options like IT *******, RN *******, RC *******, BN ******* and many more but it has not been going. please help me!!!

fill the form in this format "CAC/IT/IT000000"
